# Change GridViewColumn header color

Tags: wpf, listview

I have this ListView:

```
<ListView  Name="lvFiles" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="File name" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="50" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can i set the Header color ?

Answer (score 12):

I have not used `GridView` personally, but a quick web search led me to:

[GridView Column Header Styles and Templates Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748988.aspx)

That page links out to other pages to explain various things you can do with `GridView` column headers. It looks like there are multiple ways to set the "color" (not sure if you mean `Foreground` or `Background`), but using a `Style` seems like what you probably want. You can set a style to apply to all column headers like this:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <!-- Set any properties you want to set -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

You can override the header style for a specific column like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Something">
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <!-- Set any properties you want to set -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Style>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Edit: While you can customize most thing using styes and data templates (which are covered in the overview I linked at the top of this answer), there are certain things that are not customizable because they are baked into the control template – such as the border that appears above and below each column header. If you need to modify any of those things, then you will need to setup a style that sets the `Template` property to a custom `ControlTemplate` that you create.

If you want to make your own control template for a column header, I suggest you start by copying the [example template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) into your application resources. Then tweak the parts you need to tweak. Keep in mind that setting the `Template` property on a control completely replaces the template, meaning you have to define the entire template that you want to use, not simply define parts that you want to be different from the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please see this current state of my header: http://s3.postimg.org/65zkepm03/Untitled.png how can i remove the upper line of the header ? (only the upper one) and the lines between the headers names

Comment: Unfortunately, that border is built into the [control template for the column header control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) (named `ColumnHeaderBorder`). There is no way to modify it unless you write your own template.

Comment: Updated answer with information about overriding the control template, if it is something you want to explore.